# Como cancelar um evento INSERT pelo trigger?

Tags: mysql, trigger, eventos

Olá, eu criei um trigger que a cada vez que o usuário realiza uma venda é feita o debito na quantidade de itens, mas se eu não tomar o cuidado a quantidade pode ficar negativa pois o usuário pode vender mais do que tem no banco de dados. Sendo assim eu preciso de um trigger que não faça o INSERT daquela venda se a quantidade da venda for maior que a disponível. Para isso eu precisaria testar antes... Eu comecei algo assim

```
--Esse é um trigger BEFORE INSERT
    BEGIN
    set @qtd = SELECT itens.quantidade WHERE itens.id = NEW.itens_id;
    IF (NEW.quantidade > @qtd) THEN
        --Cancela o INSERT para que o Trigger do AFTER INSERT n faça a subtração ficando negativa no estoque 
    END IF;

    END
```

Answer (score 1):

Não é possível parar um `INSERT` pelo `TRIGGER` (ou pelo menos não sem usar uma gambiarra). Você tem duas opções nesse caso:

1. Verificar a quantidade antes de inserir o registro e exibir uma mensagem para o usuário;
2. Você pode gerar uma mensagem de erro utilizando **[SIGNAL](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/signal.html)**, tratar esse erro no seu back-end e exibir uma mensagem para o usuário¹

¹ Evite fazer gambiarras desse tipo.

Comment: Eu faria desse modo que você falou no exemplo 1.